# Format date-string from datagridview to dd/MM/yyyy in C#

Tags: c#, date, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a date column. I'm making a printable report of that datagridview.
For that I'm using this line of code:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Date"].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, x, 140 + height);
```

This gives me an output on the report in this format 11/09/2021 10:15
I'd like to have the date on the report, without the time: 11/09/2021

So far I've tried this:

- `e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Date"].FormattedValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, x, 140 + height);`: this gives me the following error: 'No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument'
- `string date = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Date"].FormattedValue.ToString(); newdate = date.Substring(0, 9);` this gives me the following error when rendering the report: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'index and length must refer to a location within the string. parameter name'

At the moment, I'm out of inspiration.....
Any suggestions?

Kind regards, Christophe

Comment: What is the underlying data source for the grid view?

Comment: You need to format the Value of the cell. FormattedValue is already a string

Comment: @Berk converting the output of _void Graphics.DrawString_ to a DateTime?

Comment: @Steve yes otherwise you can't use `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` Edit 1: I meant to convert value sorry. It should be `Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Date"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: @John the underlying data source is a database with date column. The type is timestamp and the format is 2021-01-15 08:54:50

Comment: There are a number of different approaches to formatting a `DateTime` value in a `DataGridView` object. None of them involve trying to call `ToString()` on the `FormattedValue` property's value, because `FormattedValue` returns a `string` reference, not a `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert to a datetime the property Value of your DataGridViewRow. This is typed as an object so you need a conversion. At that point you can use the overload of ToString available for the DateTime type that accepts the output format required.

For clarity I put the code in separate lines.

```
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Date"].Value);
 string toOutput = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
 e.Graphics.DrawString(toOuput, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, x, 140 + height);
```

Comment: Great! Solved my issue! Thanks!